# angular 2 add strange attributes to the doom

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2.

I am trying to make a login page. I have a app component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    template: `
    <div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>
     `,
     styleUrls:["app/app.component.css",]
})
export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'default';
}
```

and also have login component

```
  @Component({
        templateUrl: 'app/home/login.component.html',
        styleUrls: ["app/home/login.component.css"]
    })
    export class LoginComponent {
    }
```

when I run the page in the browser angular seem to add strange attribute to each elements in the doom, for example (_ngcontent-ehi,_nghost-ehi... )

```
<pm-app _nghost-ehi-1="">
    <div _ngcontent-ehi-1="">
            <router-outlet _ngcontent-ehi-1=""></router-outlet><ng-component _nghost-ehi-3="">    <div _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="formWrapper">
            <div _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="formLogo"></div>
            <div _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="welcome">
                <h4 _ngcontent-ehi-3="">Welcome</h4>
                <h4 _ngcontent-ehi-3="">Please signin</h4>
            </div>
            <form _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="loginForm">
                <input _ngcontent-ehi-3="" placeholder="Username" type="text">
                <input _ngcontent-ehi-3="" placeholder="Password" type="text">
                <div _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="cbxWrap"><input _ngcontent-ehi-3="" id="cbx1" value="rememberCbx" type="checkbox"><label _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="cbxlbl" for="cbx1">remember me</label></div>
                <input _ngcontent-ehi-3="" value="Login" type="button">
            </form>
            <div _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="forgetPass">
                <span _ngcontent-ehi-3="" style="float:left;margin-top:6px;">forgot password?</span>
                <span _ngcontent-ehi-3="" style="float:right"><img _ngcontent-ehi-3="" src="/app/assets/images/ezmanage-draft-v7_07.jpg"></span>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-ehi-3="" class="clear"></div>

    </ng-component>
     </div>
     </pm-app>
```

also css of login component is seem to be inline with strange attributes too, also some css role of it are not working because of those atrributes .

```
body[_ngcontent-amn-3] {
    background: #2d323f none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
    .loginForm[_ngcontent-ehi-3] input[type="button"][_ngcontent-ehi-3], .loginForm[_ngcontent-ehi-3] input[type="text"][_ngcontent-ehi-3] {
        border: 1px solid #888888;
        color: #888888;
        display: block;
        margin: 1em auto 0;
        padding: 1em 3%;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        width: 94%;
    }
```

what are those attribute in the doom?why "login.component.css" is inline  inside the page and role has strange attributes too?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These attributes are added to emulate style encapsulation. Also the selectors for the styles added to components are rewritten to only match these attributes.

If you change `encapsulation` or `@Component()` to `ViewEncapsulation.None` or `ViewEncapsulation.Native` these attributes are not used and style selectors not rewritten.

Comment: thanks,  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None inside a Component return error:cant find name ViewEncapsulatio, any idea why?

Comment: You need to import it from `@angular/core`. See for examples http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 1):

In short- Angular does some stuff to the DOM... Take a read through the link below for more information.

> "Angular has to make sure that the component’s style selectors only match this particlar component and nothing else on the page. That’s why it extends the CSS selectors, so they have a higher specificity and don’t collide with other selectors defined before at the same. And of course, to make those selectors actually match, the elements in the template need to be extended as well. That’s why we see all those `_ngcontent-*` and `_nghost-*` attributes."
>   ~ [View Encapsulation in Angular 2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)

There is also a fair amount of information on how and why Angular does what  it does at [Angular 2 Architecture](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html).